# Remove brackets and special characters from string and convert List (Values are comma separated)

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, list, logic

I have a string like below.

> {[Utilisa. du domaine, jira-users, confluence-users, jira-developers,
>   Product Team India, 'test-1', "Product Group", Atlassian-Stash,
>   awspreprod-readonly, awsprod-readonly, awspreprod-rddevops,
>   awsrddev-readonly, awsrddev-rddevops, test.user]}

Now i want to make a List of this elements by removing **(){}'"** scpecial characters.

I know i can remove bracket by using some regex or below method.

```
s = 'Barack (of Washington)'
bad_chars = '(){}<>'
s.translate(string.maketrans("", "", ), bad_chars)
```

But i want to remove extra or multiple spaces and also if there is something like a;b;c,c then also i have consider this as 4 elements whether its a ; or ,

Expected Output:

> [Utilisa.dudomaine,jira-users,confluence-users,jira-developers,ProductTeamIndia,test-1,ProductGroup,Atlassian-Stash,awspreprod-readonly,awsprod-readonly,awspreprod-rddevops,awsrddev-readonly,awsrddev-rddevops,test.user]

Any best idea?

Thanks!

Comment: post the final expected result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thanks for pointing. Suggested changes done :)

Comment: Why not add the unwanted characters to your `bad_chars` (eg. `bad_chars = "(){}<>'\" "`)?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest He is right. Any good suggestion?

Comment: @I'L'I To apply regex and convert into list using single statement is what i was looking for. 
Please have a look on below Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`re.split()`** function solution:

```
import re

s = '''{[Utilisa. du domaine, jira-users, confluence-users, jira-developers, Product Team India, 'test-1', "Product Group", Atlassian-Stash, awspreprod-readonly, awsprod-readonly, awspreprod-rddevops, awsrddev-readonly, awsrddev-rddevops, test.user]'''

result = [i for i in re.split(r'\s*[{}<>\[\],;\'"]\s*', s) if i]
print(result)
```

The output:

```
['Utilisa. du domaine', 'jira-users', 'confluence-users', 'jira-developers', 'Product Team India', 'test-1', 'Product Group', 'Atlassian-Stash', 'awspreprod-readonly', 'awsprod-readonly', 'awspreprod-rddevops', 'awsrddev-readonly', 'awsrddev-rddevops', 'test.user']
```

Comment: `re.split` is adding single quote by default? While converting to string?
Because in regex you have removed `'` i guess.
Let me correct if i am wrong!

Comment: Your solution is perfect! 
Thanks :)

Comment: @JayeshDhandha, you're welcome (Note, your output should have contained quoted strings as items of a list)

Comment: This regex is removing brackets from everywhere. What should i modify if i want to remove brackets only from the beginning and end?

Comment: @JayeshDhandha, you are free to create a new question with new requirements. Thanks